# Why am I having difficulty embedding images with HTML tags?

Tags: support, markdown

Whenever I attempt to embed an image with HTML tags on the French Stack Exchange, it does not work.

```
<a href="https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidney_bean"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Red_Rajma_BNC.jpg" 
 width=”100″ > </a>
```

[Here are the html tags which the we site rules say are allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/610179)

Answer (score 2):

The documented tags works fine.
The issue is the incorrect opening quote character you use before `100`:

## **”** ≠ **"**

.

```
<a href="https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidney_bean">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Red_Rajma_BNC.jpg" width="320">
</a>
```

[image]